# Three.js + Internet Explorer 11 = FLICKERING

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js, flicker

I've been using Three.js to modelize 3D wells (for oil prospection).

Very simple, no texture, no lighting.
Using a WebGL renderer with antialias on, frustumCulled at true.
Using a simple perspectiveCamera.

Simple animation loop (I've created a GlobalCanvas object hence the "this") :

```
// Display - Loop
this.animate = function () {
    this.animationId = requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );
    this.controls.update();
    this.render();        
}
```

**Everything is working very fine on Chrome** but I'm experiencing flickering problems on Internet Explorer 11 (these are our only 2 browser recommanded for using our solution).

- I've tried to display an empty canvas (without any object drawn on it) and the flickering problem still occurs.
- I've tried to use the "software rendering" instead of the "GPU rendering" (Advanced Internet Options) and it fixes the issue, but it's not a satisfying solution for  our customers and the rendering is in lower quality.
- I've been looking on stack**overflow** if anyone experienced this issue before but couldn't find any answer so far.

Comment: Problem fixed by setting the preserveDrawingBuffer at true for the renderer (if it can help someone).

Answer (score 4):

Written by Arnaud:

> Problem fixed by setting the preserveDrawingBuffer at true for the
>   renderer (if it can help someone).